# Node.js reference error - ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this original code:

```
const getLexSorted = (s) => {

  return s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, '').split(/\s+/g).reduce((a,b) => {

    if(!a.has(b)){
     a.set(b,0); 
    }
    let v = a.get(b);
    a.set(b,++v);
    return a;

  }, new Map());

};
```

all it does is group the sentence into words, by count. 
I changed it to this just to see what happens:

```
const getLexSorted = (s) => {

  return s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, '').split(/\s+/g).reduce((a,b) => {
    return a.has(b) ? a.set(b,++a.get(b)) : a.set(b,1), a;
  }, new Map());

};
```

and I got this error:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I tried putting extra parentheses around it -

```
 return a.has(b) ? a.set(b,++(a.get(b))) : a.set(b,1), a;
```

same thing:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`++` is an assignment operator, so you'll need something you can assign a value to. `a.get(b)` is not something you can assign a value to.

Simple solution:

```js
const getLexSorted = (s) => {

  return s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, '').split(/\s+/g).reduce((a,b) => {
    return a.has(b) ? a.set(b,a.get(b)+1) : a.set(b,1), a;
  }, new Map());

};

console.log(
  [...getLexSorted('a a b c d e e e f f g')]
)
```

For fun, here's one without `return` statements:

```js
const getLexSorted = (s) => 
  s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, '').split(/\s+/g).reduce((a,b) => (
    a.has(b) ? a.set(b,a.get(b)+1) : a.set(b,1), a
  ), new Map());

console.log(
  [...getLexSorted('a a b c d e e e f f g')]
)
```

And here's a solution using `++`, just to illustrate how you could use that operator by prefixing it to an assignable term:

```js
const getLexSorted = (s) => {
  let tmp

  return s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, '').split(/\s+/g).reduce((a,b) => {
    return a.has(b) ? (tmp = a.get(b), a.set(b,++tmp)) : a.set(b,1), a;
  }, new Map());

};

    console.log(
      [...getLexSorted('a a b c d e e e f f g')]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The target of a `++` operation has to be something that can appear on the left side of an assignment expression. The subexpression `a.get(b)` is not such a thing.

You could in this case just use `a.get(b) + 1`, since the code never uses the value again.