# Array.prototype.at and the postfix/prefix increment/decrement operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-next

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3];
```

this works just fine:

```js
++nums[2] // 4
```

but this does not:

```js
++nums.at(-1) // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation
```

Can someone please explain to me?
It feels like it should work!!

Thank you

Comment: Returning value from a method can never be pre/post incremented. Same as how you cannot pre/post increment a literal `5++`. You can only do it to variables or object properties.

Comment: or `const get5 = () => 5; get5()++` or `let someNum = 5; const getNum = () => someNum; getNum()++`

Comment: `nums.at(-1)` is not a reference, `nums[2]` is. `++` only works with Reference Records.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59440689/1048572